# Will I keep my progress if I change account?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have been playing for almost 2 days, and today it is asking me to sign up again.

I have all my game saved in my google account, but I wonder if I just log in from a trainer account will I keep my progress?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, that would be a different account with its own progress. Your data is only on your google account.